Why my exe file is running fine on old laptop but giving abnormal output on new laptop
I am running my C project using cmake on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, x86_64. The project is working fine. Now I want to transfer my project from this laptop to new laptop. When i build and run the project again in new laptop, it builds fine but gives incorrect output.
By incorrect output, i mean:

segmentation fault at some random point.
execution of program stopped at random point without giving any error.

New laptop uses Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, x86_64.
The dependencies of executable in old laptop are:
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc489df000) libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000782745a00000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000782745e1a000)
Whereas in new laptop:
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc31d1000) libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007aca04000000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007aca042ec000)
I tried:

reinstall libc6
Checked library paths using sudo ldconfig -p | grep libc.so.6 on both laptops and old laptop has 1 entry more: libc.so.6 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib32/libc.so.6, this entry isnot present in new laptop.
lib/i386-linux-gnu path were missing in new laptop which i added manually


I don't think the information you have provided enables anyone to produce a useful answer. Check whether the computer is ok (are other things crashing? memtest passes?). And then try to catch a segfault (or several) with a debugger and analyze what is going on.

Possibilites: software incompatibility, hardware problems (bad memory, 13 or 14 series Intel CPU), undefined behavior in code (memory and/or multithreading)...

@teapot418 i am cloning a git project in both laptops. 1 laptop giving correct output while other is giving incorrect.

What is the hardware of both laptops? What is their architecture?

@Thugmek x86_64

Please provide more info. What exact hardware do you have in your laptop? x86_64 is quite wide term, there are various hardware modules inside CPU, which your code may depend on. If this is not handled properly and required module is missing, you won't have required instruction implemented and get segmentation fault.

@Thugmek Linux 6.8.0-50-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. Architecture: x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:          39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:             Little Endian
